# maximize common ground or expand common ground as widely as possible

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, collocations

> "maximize common ground"

or

> "expand common ground as widely as possible"

Which one is more proper?

I looked up "**maximize**" in dictionaries. It says that the word is used to increase or make use of something as much as possible. But I am not sure that "maximize" can be collocated with "common ground".

Comment: Both are proper. They mean the same thing. Which to use depends on the context.

Comment: To my ear, the "collocation" that *doesn't* work here is ***maximise*** plus ***as widely as possible***, because as you've already discovered from your dictionary research, maximising something already means to make it as big as possible. Tautology isn't *always* a bad thing in English, but I think it looks clumsy here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a little unclear if he's asking if "maximize common ground" and "expand common ground as widely as possible" are both acceptable, or if it's "[maximize/expand] common ground as widely as possible". "Expand[ing] common ground as widely as possible" isn't wrong, but it feels a little clunky to me so I'd say "maximize common ground" is probably the preferred choice here, but it could depend heavily on context.

Comment: To my mind, ***broaden** the common ground as/so **far** as possible* would be a much better way of expressing it. But that's really just Off Topic "writing advice".

Comment: Maybe "common ground" is not a thing for which measurement words apply? Not confident about that at all. But maybe "expand on common ground" or "build on common ground" or some such?

Comment: Neither are idiomatic. The comments above suggest better alternatives.